# Find the expectation from a distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let , $X$ be a random variable having distribution function $$F(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if } x<0\\\frac{1}{4}&\text{ if }0\le x<1\\\frac{1}{3}&\text{ if }1\le x<2\\\frac{1}{2}&\text{ if }2\le x<\frac{11}{3}\\1&\text{ if }x\ge \frac{11}{3}\end{cases}$$Find $E(X)$.

**Attempt :**

$P(X=x)=F(x)-F(x-0)$. Now , $\displaystyle E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xP(X=x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x[F(x)-F(x-0)]\,dx$

$$=\int_{-\infty}^0x(0-0)\,dx+\int_0^1x[F(x)-F(x-0)]\,dx+\int_1^2x[F(x)-F(x-0)]\,dx+\int_2^{11/3}x[F(x)-F(x-0)]\,dx+\int_{11/3}^{\infty}x[F(x)-F(x-0)]\,dx$$Am I in right direction ?

Comment: yes, you are. And the integrals reduce to sum when you moving on ($X$ is a simple random variable).

Comment: While this does work, if a random variable has a piecewise constant CDF then it has a PMF. Calculating the expectation from the PMF would be easier. Similarly, if a random variable has a continuously differentiable (or more generally, absolutely continuous) CDF, then it has a PDF, and it is easier to calculate the expectation using the PDF.

Comment: @lan How I find the sum ? Is it sum at the points $0,1,2,11/3$ ?

Comment: I wonder how one can write $F(0) - F(x - 0)$ and not say this evaluates to zero everywhere, hence the integrals are all zero. Obviously zero is not the correct answer, so there must be a better way to write the calculation.

Comment: Contrarily to what some comments you received assert, the integral formulation in your question is a deadend (since the distribution of X has no density (with respect to Lebesgue measure) part, if you want to know...). For example, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty xP(X=x)dx=0$$ but, fortunately, this fact is not even related to the question. As an answer below show, one should first identify the distribution of X (sum of four Dirac measures) and deduce everything from that. For a (mainly useless) formula, valid for every discrete random variable, try $$E(X)=\sum_{x:F(x)\ne F(x^-)}x\,(F(x)-F(x^-)).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this cdf, it can be identified $X$ is a discrete random variable, and the jumps occur at points $0, 1, 2, 11/3$, with jump sizes $1/4, 1/3 - 1/4, 1/2 - 1/3$ and $1 - 1/2$. Therefore,
$$E(X) = 0 \times \frac{1}{4} + 1 \times \left(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}\right) + 2 \times \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3}\right) + \frac{11}{3} \times \left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{11}{6} = \frac{27}{12}.$$